# How to have useful assertion-failure messages for FsUnit?

Tags: f#, nunit, fsunit

I'm using FsUnit 2.3.2 and I'm not happy with the failure messages. See the examples below:

```
[<Test>]
let ``test 1``() =
    [1; 3]
    |> should equal [1;2]
```

... gives me the not-so-helpful message:

> Expected and actual are both
>   Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.FSharpList`1[System.Int32]
>
> at FsUnit.TopLevelOperators.should[a,a](FSharpFunc`2 f, a x, Object y)
>   in d:\GitHub\FsUnit\src\FsUnit.NUnit\FsUnit.fs:line 44 at Program.test
>   1() in F:\work\playground\fsunit\fsunit\Program.fs:line 9

A workaround that I found was to use arrays instead of lists:

```
[<Test>]
let ``test 2``() =
    [|1; 4|]
    |> should equal [|1;2|]
```

...produces

> Expected and actual are both System.Int32[2]
>     Values differ at index [1]
>     Expected: 2
>     But was:  4

A second problem is if I have an ADT defined

```
type MyT = 
    A of int 
    | B of string

[<Test>]
let ``test 4``() =
    A 10
    |> should equal (B "abc")
```

...gives me the message:

> Expected: Program+MyT+B
>     But was:  Program+MyT+A

...which I can workaround by implementing ToString for MyT like this:

```
override this.ToString() = match this with
    | A i -> sprintf "A(%d)" i
    | B s -> sprintf "B(%s)" s
```

...which will lead to a good message:

> Expected: B(abc)
>     But was:  A(10)

...but I would like fsunit to just render MyT values the way (sprintf "%A") does.

Anyway, having to do these workarounds is NOT OK.

How can I obtain useful messages for F# lists without using arrays?

How to obtain useful messages for ADTs?

Is there a good fix for the above issues or should I just drop FsUnit?

Do you have a better recommendation for a unit testing library for F# that doesn't have these issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of contenders:

**[Expecto](https://github.com/haf/expecto)**

```
[<Tests>]
let tests =
  testList "test group" [
    testCase "strings" <| fun _ ->
        let subject = "Hello World"
        Expect.equal subject "Hello world"
                    "The strings should be equal"

    testCase "lists" <| fun _ ->
        let expected = [1; 2]   
        Expect.equal expected [1; 3]
                    "The lists should be equal"

    testCase "DUs" <| fun _ ->
        let expected = A 10   
        Expect.equal expected (B "abc")
    ]
```

Output

> ```
> [19:29:46 INF] EXPECTO? Running tests...
> [19:29:46 ERR] test group/strings failed in 00:00:00. 
> The strings should be equal.
>           Expected string to equal:
>           "Hello world"
>                  ↑
>           The string differs at index 6.
>           "Hello World"
>                  ↑
>           String does not match at position 6. Expected char: 'w', but got 'W'.
>
> [19:29:46 ERR] test group/lists failed in 00:00:00. 
> The lists should be equal. Actual value was [1; 2] but had expected it to be [1; 3].
>
> [19:29:46 ERR] test group/DUs failed in 00:00:00. 
> The DUs should be equal. Actual value was A 10 but had expected it to be B "abc".
>
> [19:29:46 INF] EXPECTO! 3 tests run in 00:00:00.0028417 – 0 passed, 0 ignored, 3 failed, 0 errored. ( ರ Ĺ̯ ರೃ )
> val it : int = 1
> ```

**[Unquote](https://github.com/SwensenSoftware/unquote)**

```
[<Test>]
let ``The strings should be equal`` () =
    let subject = "Hello World"
    subject =! "Hello world"
```

> ```
> Result Message:   
> "Hello World" = "Hello world"
> false
> ```

```
[<Test>]
let ``The lists should be equal`` () =
    let expected = [1; 2]
    expected =! [1; 3]
```

> ```
> Result Message:   
> [1; 2] = [1; 3]
> false
> ```

```
[<Test>]
let ``The DUs should be equal`` () =
    let expected = A 10
    expected =! (B "abc")
```

> ```
> Result Message:   
> A 10 = B "abc"
> false
> ```

Unquote's benefit lies in it's `Quotations`, allowing step-by-step failure messages.

```
[<Test>]
let ``The arrays should be equal`` () =
    let expected = [|0 ; 2 ; 3 ; 4|]
    test <@ (Array.map ((+) 1) [|0 .. 3|]) = expected @>
```

> ```
> Result Message:   
> Array.map ((+) 1) [|0..3|] = [|0; 2; 3; 4|]
> Array.map ((+) 1) [|0; 1; 2; 3|] = [|0; 2; 3; 4|]
> [|1; 2; 3; 4|] = [|0; 2; 3; 4|]
> false
> ```

Comment: Expecto looks good but does it integrate with a build system based on nunit?

Comment: @vidi I don't know, you might want to ask a new question to find out.